# shell script + mutt: mutt terminating while loop

Tags: scripts, mutt

I am having a problem with *mutt* exiting my while loop prematurely in my shell script.
The *while read MAILTO* loop of my function *sendFiles* will only process (send) the first file and then returns. However, if I comment-out '/usr/bin/mutt' from the function all the files in the directory are processed properly.

Anyone know why this behaviour is occurring and how to fix it?

```
#!/bin/sh
# sendReports.sh

# sendFiles function    
sendFiles ()
{
  cd $1
  ls -1 *@* | while read MAILTO
  do
    echo "Emailing file: $MAILTO"
    /usr/bin/mutt -s "Your file" -a $MAILTO -- $MAILTO
    rm -f $MAILTO
  done
}

# .... later in the life of this script ....
sendFiles /tmp/reports

# (end of file)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mutt goes into interactive mode after sending an Email, this breaks you out of the loop add `< /dev/null` at the end of your mutt request

Example:

`/usr/bin/mutt -s "Your file" -a $MAILTO -- $MAILTO < /dev/null`